# asp.net and multi threading and C# object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.net programming and I don't really understand the thing about multi threading . When I debug in my ASP.net app/website it shows a tab that I'm not familiar with: Parallel watch, it's something about multi threading. When I search about multi threading I only find examples about how to use multi-threading etc. The thing is, I'm not using any class for threading.

What I got in my code:

is my main page:
`Index.aspx.cs`:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Message = PLC1.Connect();

    lblClock.Text = Message;    
}
```

and

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(PLC1.x_ConnectionEstablished)
    {
        string Message;

        Message = PLC1.ReadDB(1, 0, 17);

        if (Message == "OK")
        {
            lblClock.Text = "Connected and retrieved value!!";
        }
        else
        {
            lblClock.Text = Message;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblClock.Text = "No connection! Press the button!";
    }      
}
```

my class: `PLC.cs`:

```
public string Connect()
{
    int Result;
    string Message;

    Result = s7_S7Client.ConnectTo(s_IP, i_Rack, i_Slot);
    Message = s7_S7Client.ErrorText(Result);

    x_ConnectionEstablished = s7_S7Client.Connected();

    return Message;
}

public string ReadDB(int a_DBnr, int a_startPos, int a_size)
{
    int Result;
    string Message = "";

    try
    {
        Result = s7_S7Client.DBRead(a_DBnr, a_startPos, a_size, bArray_Buffer);
        Message = s7_S7Client.ErrorText(Result);
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        Message = E.Message;
    }

    return Message;
}
```

When I press the button (while debugging) it jumps to the `Connect()` of my PLC class. And it actually gives true on the `x_ConnectionEstablished`. But when my Timer triggers it doesn't go into my  if-statement. Since it's saying: `x_ConnectionEstablished = false`.

I can add the code to the timer, but I don't want to execute the connection method each time I get in the timer(that's what I'm using this `x_connectionEstablished` for.

So my question is how does this threading work and how can I get my website running decently with or without the threading?

Comment: This has nothing to do with threading. It appears your `PLC1` is reset upon every request, i.e. on every button click. Peristent connections from web applications are generally a bad idea.

Comment: And how can I call my `PLC1` creation once per page startup? It's now just at the top of my `index.aspx.cs` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PLC1` and `s7_S7Client` appear to create some kind of persistent connection, for example through TCP sockets or a serial connection.

You don't want to create connections like this from an HTTP back-end, because HTTP is (or at least supposed to be) stateless: each request starts with a clean slate, all your variables (and thus connections) from the previous request are gone.

So I would advise wrapping this logic into a Windows Service that manages connecting to the PLC, and exposing the logic from this service through WCF.

Then your web application can issue requests, through WCF, to the service, and the service in turn talks to the PLC and maintains the connection.

Comment: I kinda used a C# app before to connect to a PLC before. And that worked perfectly fine. I think I should rebuild that a bit and send the information to my webpage.

Comment: The point is not the code. It's the nature of the web. Each request starts with a clean slate, so your connection is gone on the next request. If you want to persist the connection between requests, you've got to do so outside the ASP.NET context.

Comment: No I mean, I've build a C# application before (without ASP.NET) that works perfectly fine with a stable connection to the PLC. I just need to find a way to send information from my C# app to my website. But that's not the problem on this case. You've pushed me into the right direction and I thank you for that :)